# Cakephp jquery mobile refresh reload to see the correct url

Tags: cakephp, jquery-mobile, refresh, reload

I'm developing mobile version of a web application with cakephp and jquery mobile and I can't solve the following problem:

Logging in is working and it brings me to the log in page, but this is not reflected in the URL. I have to reload the page to see the proper url. And it happens the same on every page of the site. I guess I'm missing something in the `BeforeFilter` or `AfterFilter` function.
What am I missing? What I'm doing wrong?

Steps what is happening:

1. I enter the email and password in the index page.
2. When I submmit, the application brings me to the log in page.
3. The url is still the index url!
4. When I reload the page the url is automatically changed to the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should add redirect URL to the Auth Component:

```
        'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'),
    )
```

And use it in the login action on succesful login:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}
```

Depends on how you handle login process, this is the classic way with no AJAX involved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that I'm not using the Auth component. When successful log in I use the redirect function. Apparently it redirects to the log in page, but it is not reflected on the URL. Once I reload the page everything's fine.

Comment: In the BeforeFilter function in AppController I have the following: if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
   
  $this->is_mobile = true;
         $this->set('is_mobile', true );
   
                $viewDir = App::path('View'); 
            $mobileViewFile = $viewDir[0] . $this->viewPath.'/mobile/'.$this->params['action'] . '.ctp';
 
            $this->layout = 'mobile';
            $mobileView = $this->viewPath . '/mobile/';
            $this->viewPath = $mobileView;
   
        }

Comment: And in the UsersController when I checked that log in is sucsses I use $this->redirect(array('controller' => '....', 'action' => 'login', $parameter)); It's weird because in the desktop version it's working perfectly and URL is fine but not in the mobile version

Comment: I suggest that you check ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) if its working the way it should.